# presentScene() not a member of SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

My problem is that when I tried to move to my next Scene using self.scene?.presentScene() an error message pops up and says 'presentScene is not a member of SKScene'.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        let start = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
        start.position = CGPoint (x: self.frame.width/2-75, y: self.frame.height/2+100)
        start.fontSize = 35
        start.text = "Start"
        addChild(start)
            }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */
        let MyScene = SecondScene(size: self.size)
        MyScene.scaleMode = scaleMode
        self.scene?.presentScene(MyScene)

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the docs for `presentScene`. What class does it belong to? Hint: It's not `SKScene`.

Comment: rmaddy 4 it belongs to the UIViewController but how would I be able to incorporate that into my code?

Comment: Huh? `presentScene` is a function of the `SKView` class. See the documentation.

Comment: oh my bad but how can i see the documentation i am new to swift with no prior knoledge to XCode?

Comment: How are you writing code if you have never viewed the documentation? View it in Xcode by bringing up the "Documentation and API Reference" window. Or view it online at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/

Comment: Or option-click just about anything in your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`presentScene` is a method of `SKView`, not `SKScene`.

So to load a new scene you should write something like this

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let myScene = SecondScene(size: self.size)
        myScene.scaleMode = scaleMode
        self.view?.presentScene(myScene)
    }
}
```

### Transition

You can also present the new scene with a transition effect. In this case one this method and pass a SKTransition as second param.

```
self.view?.presentScene(myScene, transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1))
```

In the example above I am using a Cross Fade transition having a duration of 1 second. But there are many other transitions to choose from.